# Variables in __init__.py file not being passed into view in Flask app

Tags: python, flask

I'm working through the beginnings of a Flask tutorial and am trying to manually pass variables into a view template (called index.html) from the `__init__.py` file.

Here is the index.html file:

```
<html>
<head>
</head>

<body>
    <h3>{{ title }}</h3>
    <p>{{ paragraph }}</p>
</body>
</html>
```

and here is the `__init__.py` file:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template

app = Flask(__name__)
@app.route('/')
def homepage():
    return render_template("index.html", title = "Epic Tutorials", paragraph = "test")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

The view loads on the server when I replace the contents of the H3 and P tags with conventional words like you'd see on an HTML page without the curly braces, but I get a blank page when I add the curly braces, and am not sure how to rectify this.

Comment: The terminal running the server should show an error. What does it say?

Comment: 127.0.0.1 - - [28/Jun/2015 20:44:51] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 -
127.0.0.1 - - [28/Jun/2015 20:53:42] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 -
127.0.0.1 - - [28/Jun/2015 20:54:13] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 -
127.0.0.1 - - [28/Jun/2015 20:54:14] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 -
127.0.0.1 - - [28/Jun/2015 20:54:14] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 -
127.0.0.1 - - [28/Jun/2015 20:54:15] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 -
127.0.0.1 - - [28/Jun/2015 20:55:16] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 -
127.0.0.1 - - [28/Jun/2015 20:57:05] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 -
127.0.0.1 - - [28/Jun/2015 20:57:06] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 -
127.0.0.1 - - [28/Jun/2015 20:57:16] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 -

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`__init__.py` is special; it's how you [demark a package](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html#packages).

You **don't want** to put your code there.  Create a flat file for it instead.  You could even rename `__init__.py` to something else, like `init` or `index`.